# Stop capturing the webcam without freezing in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, video-capture

Im developing an application in AS3 wich captures the webcam images.

When this part is finished i simply remove the webcam and all works very well.

But sometimes when i remove it, the application freeze some seconds.

It seems that the app is waiting something form the webcam.

Im utilizing this code:

```
cam = Camera.getCamera();   
cam.setQuality(0, 80);
cam.setMode(533, 400, 20);
video = new Video(533,400);
video.attachCamera(cam);
video.x = 0;
video.y = 0;
addChild(video);
```

To remove:

```
removeChild(video);
cam = null;
video.attachCamera(null);
video = null;
```

Is there a way to not wait?
Or the problem is outside of the reach of my application?

Comment: Code looks fine to me... but i always detach the camera before nulling it - ie: video.attachCamera(null) before cam=null.

Comment: Agreed, your code is fine... that's the proper way to disconnect the camera. Setting it to null first or last should not matter. What I suspect matters is the environment. I've never encountered this problem. the behavior may be specific to your camera, camera driver, camera settings (mode/quality), OS, browser, Flash Player, etc. Can you reproduce this on another machine? Try different settings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this, in my case I had also attached the camera to a NetStream. The solution for me was to attach a null camera to the netstream before I attached the null camera to the video instance.